# PowerShell generating CSV file with ASCI encoding due to hashed field instead of UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, encoding

I wrote a PowerShell script that outputs the data from a number of SQL Server tables into csv files. The files are consumed further downstream by a financial application. The script is shown below.

```
Write-Host 1
#############################################################
#
# - Name: Create_Ldr_Files_GDM
#
# - Purpose: This script exports GDM tables to csv for WKSaaas
#
#############################################################
# - Change history:
# - Date      Intials    Notes
# - --------  -------    ------------------------------------
# - 20231204  EOS      Initial Version
# - 
#############################################################

#############################################################
#                     Functions                             *
#############################################################
$RepoDsn        = ${env:WSL_META_DSN}
$p_gdm_ldr_param_path   = "Path_GDM_AC"
$p_gdm_ctl_param_path   = "Path_GDM_ctl_AC"

# save current CUlture info
$OldCulture = [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

# start trap to make sure it reverts should anything break
trap {
    [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture
}

# set the new Culture.
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [cultureInfo]::GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag('en-US')



function get_param_value ($p_gdm_ldr_param_path, $RepoDsn){
    $sql = "select [dbo].[WsParameterReadF] ('$p_gdm_ldr_param_path') as src_path"
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=$RepoDsn;Uid=$RepoUser;Pwd=$RepoPass"
    $conn.open()
    $cmd = [system.data.odbc.odbcCommand]::new($sql,$conn) 
    $adapter = [system.data.odbc.odbcDataAdapter]::new($cmd) 
    $dr = [system.data.dataSet]::new() 
    [Void]$adapter.Fill($dr) 
    $conn.close()
    $path_file = $dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["src_path"]
    
    return $path_file
}

$server =  ${env:WSL_META_SERVER} 
$database = "PUB_FINANCE"
$tablequery = "SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM [PUB_FINANCE].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA ='gdm' AND TABLE_TYPE = 'VIEW' AND (TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'mapping%' and TABLE_NAME != 'vw_gdm_ACBS_LodAmount')"
$fileDirectory =  get_param_value $p_gdm_ldr_param_path $RepoDsn 
$ctlFileDirectory = get_param_value $p_gdm_ctl_param_path $RepoDsn

#Delcare Connection Variables
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
 
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $tablequery
$command.Connection = $connection
 
#Load up the Tables in a dataset
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()

# delete contents of output directory

Get-Childitem -Path $fileDirectory | Remove-Item

# Loop through all tables and export a CSV of the Table Data
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    $queryData = "SELECT * FROM [PUB_FINANCE].[gdm].[$($Row[0])]"

    #Specify the output location of your dump file
    $extractFile = "$($fileDirectory)\$($Row[0]).ldr"

    #have to remove the vw_ from the file name as data is coming from staging out views but filename needs to be the same as the table
    #eg vw_COUNTERPARTY.ctl -> COUNTERPARTY.ctl
    $parseExtractFile =  $extractFile.replace('vw_','')
     
    $command.CommandText = $queryData
    $command.Connection = $connection
 
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $connection.Close()
         
   #Create csv with headers only if no data is found in the gdm table
        if ($DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count -eq 0) {
  #$header = ""
   # foreach ($col in $DataSet.Tables[0].Columns) {
   #     $header += $col.ColumnName +","
   # }
     Out-File $parseExtractFile}
#} 
  else {
   $DataSet.Tables[0]  |  ConvertTo-Csv  -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1| Set-Content $parseExtractFile
  }
        
}

# Copy ctl files to output directory

Copy-Item -Path $ctlFileDirectory\*.ctl  -Destination $fileDirectory  

# reverts culture to the original
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = $OldCulture

$RESULT_CODE = 1
$RESULT_MSG = "ctl and loaded files have been created"
Write-Output $RESULT_CODE
Write-Output $RESULT_MSG
```

One of the fields from the table tables is a hashed and is now causing the ASCI encoded file to be produced. This encoding is causing the file to be rejected by the application. The file has to be UTF_8. The column is hashed as shown below

```
CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
               COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Data_Source_Code AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'null') +'||'+
               COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'null')
               ) AS BINARY(32)) as ide_position_ref
```

Is there a way in PowerShell to prevent the encoding from changing to ASCI?

The contents of the file looks as such:

[image]

the expectation is:

[image]

Comment: What makes you think the column type is related to the output encoding? You can control the encoding by changing `Set-Content $parseExtractFile` to `Set-Content $parseExtractFile -Encoding UTF8`. Formatting the column value depends on the expected format. Do you want to convert it to a hex string or similar?

Comment: when the column is empty the file is ok. when it is populated we get the encoding issue. There are 20 tables in total and all files are utf8 except for this particular table when that column is populated

Comment: And what does that look like in practice? How are you detecting the encoding, and what does the resulting file look like?

Comment: I got the error message from the results from loading the application. Another department handles that. I have added screenshots above

Comment: Well ASCII only defines the code points from `0x00` to `0x7F` (0-127). Since your file includes output like U+00E8 `è` (e grave) the file is clearly __not__ in ASCII encoding. If you read the _CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)_ documentation you'll notice the [Binary Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#binary-styles) section shows how to format binary data. Have you tried something like `SELECT CONVERT(char(66), ide_position_ref, 1) AS [ide_position_ref]` yet? See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5k2X08Z9)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to convert the hash value to a (hex-formatted) string instead of `binary(32)`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(66), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',
               COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Data_Source_Code AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'null') +'||'+
               COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Id AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'null')
               ), 1) as ide_position_ref
```

Comment: I just used  the following which  worked.                                                                                                                              CONVERT(
      VARCHAR(32),
      HASHBYTES(
                   'MD5',
                   COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Data_Source_Code AS VARCHAR(250)),'null') +'||'+
                    COALESCE(CAST(Dim_Protection_Received.Protection_Id AS VARCHAR(250)),'null')
               ),
      2
  )

Comment: Your question said `SHA2_256` :)

Comment: indeed my bad. I have been staring at it too long. Thanks for putting me in the right direction anyway